# How to create proper queue in RxJS consisting of Observables containing both sync and async functions

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

My application receives responses from a server. These responses may be received singly or in multiples, but they'll always be received in the order they should be individually dealt with and rendered.

Upon receiving a response, the following things need to happen, in order:

1. A typing indicator is rendered and displayed (sync)
2. The response data is parsed and massaged into the correct format (sync)
3. An artificial delay is run to emulate a "real person" typing (async)
4. The typing indicator should be removed/hidden (sync)
5. The formatted response is rendered to the screen (sync)

Now, all of these steps need to occur in order for EACH response received, ALSO in order. The end result of this should be typing indicators being shown for a random amount of time, then disappearing, then the response being shown, then the indicator being shown again for a random amount of time, then disappearing, then the next response being shown, etc.

I've tried a variety of techniques for accomplishing this with RxJS but I'm struggling to get this to work. I'm finding that regardless of my approach, responses (added to a queue-like structure and/or executed sequentially) keep firing off the chain of events concurrently. I cannot figure out how to execute the chain of events sequentially AND wait for each previous chain of events to be completed before the next begins.

I've attempted solutions using a `.pipe` chain containing `.tap` and `.concatMap` functions, as well as creating a queue from `new Subject()` and adding new items to it to be executed using `next()`. None of these things solves my problem.

It's essential that the core construct be a queue of some sort that I can continue adding items to and they'll automatically be executed when the queue is finished/empty.

Comment: why doesn't subject and concatMap work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`concatMap` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap).  Change callback to update your UI/state in the example below and it should do the job:

```js
const { of, concat } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { delay, concatMap } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const responses$ = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

const events$ = responses$.pipe(
  // concatMap to process items sequantually
  concatMap(e => {
    const typing$ = of({ type: "typing" });
    // add delay before receiving new message
    const message$ = of({ type: "new message", message: e }).pipe(delay(3000));
    
    // add delay before each response
    return concat(typing$, message$).pipe(delay(2000));
  })
);

events$.subscribe((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I was under the impression that I could chain functions, rather than wrap all my functionality within one `concatMap` call. For instance, I was using a number of `.tap()` and `.concatMap()` calls in sequence within `.pipe()`, much like you'd see in an old Promise chain with a bunch of `.then()` calls. I'm guessing/assuming the sync `tap()` calls were throwing off the async `concatMap()` call? I'll give your approach a shot and report back, thanks!

Comment: Accepted because this did work for my use case, so thanks! I still find myself a bit boggled that the optimal solution is to apparently `concat` a chain of `of` Observables and then have to check their `type` property to determine how/when to fire my actual callbacks. I just wanted to be able to `concat` together actual function calls with the `message$` Observable and have them all execute in series, as such: `return concat(showTyping(), message$, hideTyping()).pipe(delay(2000));`. Oh well, this'll work for now!

Comment: Usually it's better to keep observables pure(free of side effects) otherwise it's easy to have unpredictable behaviour and mess things up